# Joining 2 row of data into 1 row of data

Tags: mysql

I have a table which looks like this

```
|Application No | Status | Amount | Type |
==========================================
|90909090       | Null   | 3,000  | Null |
|90909090       | Forfeit| Null   | A    |
```

What I want to achieve is to combine the values together and end with a result like

```
|Application No | Status | Amount | Type |
==========================================
|90909090       | Forfeit| 3,000  | A    |
```

I am new to SQL Query and have no idea how to do this
Thanks in advance

Comment: Search for aggregate functions. For your case, `max` or `min` would be a good choice.

Comment: What would you want your output to look like if the input table also had this row (90909090, 'Gain', 1000, 'A')? If such a combination of rows is possible, you should edit your post to include this new information.

Comment: @jeff6times7 nop the table only will have 2 same Application No and only one of it have a value while the other is null

Comment: @TinTin Declaring your constraints in the question will help you get better answers faster. You were fortunate this time.

Comment: @jeff6times7 will do next time still new here :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to join, use `max()` aggregate function and `group by`:

```
select applicationno, max(status), max(amount), max(type)
from yourtable
group by applicationno
```

However, if you have several non-null values for an application number in a field, then you may have to define a more granular rule than a simple aggregation via max.